# Gitlab CI doesn't behave as expected when c++ program changes directory

Tags: c++, process, gitlab-ci

let's assume in my code there is a system process to do. However, i have to change directory before doing so and the going back, that step is necessary, no simple way to circumvent this operation.

```
std::filesystem::current_directory("child/");
std::process::system(command);
std::filesystem::current_directory("../");
```

This works in my local machine, however, in my gitlab-ci runner, which runs in the same relative path as in local, it seems that is incapable of changing the current directory, and runs the command in the directory the script was placed:

```
testing:
stage: testing
image: 
    #same OS and similar environment as local
    name: myhub/archlinux
script:
    - export BOOST_INCLUDEDIR="/usr/include/boost/"
    - export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR="/usr/lib/"
    - cd build/tests
    - ./buildUStests
```

Is there a way to tell the runner to be more flexible when the program demands to change the current directory? Or do i have to use another way to make the runner change directories?

Comment: I doubt you can get a quality answer without telling us what `command` is, and its content.

Comment: sadly the project is too complicate to explain, but it executes g++. ex: g++ test/a.o test/ b.o  -o exe -L/usr/lib -ltest

Comment: Could you explain exactly what the observed behavior is and what the expected behavior is? If possible, the output of your job might be helpful. It should work pretty much the same as locally...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, I actually found the issue.

GitLab and git essentially don't incorporate empty directories, which my program relies on, into my repo.

This means that if I roll my tests without knowing that behavior, it seems as if my program refuses to change directory.

The solution to the problem is to create the directory at execution, then make the shell commands.